# after own descriptor, the attribute is missing in __dict__

Tags: python, descriptor

i would like to add to attributes of an object in Python some information. Later i would like to store this data in a DB, therefore it would be neat to know its format in the tables.
I think the solution from SQLAlchemy is good and i would like to do it like that.

First a short example:

```
class MyAttribute(object):

    def __init__(self, AttrType):
        self.val = None
        self.AttrType = AttrType

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.val = val


class MyClass(object):

    Attr1 = MyAttribute('int(11)')

    def __init__(self):
        self.Attr1 = 44
        self.Attr2 = 55


x = MyClass()

print("Attr1: %s"%x.Attr1)
print("Attr2: %s"%x.Attr2)

print(x.__dict__)
```

The output of this script is:

```
Attr1: 44
Attr2: 55

{'Attr2': 55}
```

Now my problem: in `__dict__`, there is `Attr2`, but not `Attr1`. Why? How can I add it? Which function is responsible for that? (My read is `__set__`, correct?) What do I have to add where to add the attribute object to the dict?

Comment: `__dict__` is an implementation detail of object instances which is used to store attributes of the instance. A descriptor simply isn't an attributeof the instance.

Comment: That's why you should use `dir(x)` rather than accessing `x.__dict__` directly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `MyClass.__dict__`:

```
>>> MyClass.__dict__['Attr1']
<__main__.MyAttribute object at 0x000000000296A5F8>
```

Descriptors are stored in the class object, not the instance object. You're actually in trouble here, for that reason:

```
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> x.Attr1
44
>>> y = MyClass()
>>> y.Attr1 = 66
>>> y.Attr1
66
>>> x.Attr1
66 # uh oh
```

It's the job of MyAttribute to keep track of which data belongs to which instance.